# Can't connect to free wifi network with iwconfig in Linux embedded

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, embedded-linux, wpa-supplicant, yocto-project

at first sorry for my English, it's very bad. I hope you will understand my problem.

I'm working on Yocto dizzy and I'm trying to manage Wi-Fi connections. On my board I have a wf111 module. When I turn on my machine I'm able to connect to free network or to protected network. Then, once connected, I'm able to switch connection from free to protected network, or from protected to other protected netowork, or from free to other free network, but I can't switch from protected to free network. In this case I get an error:

```
unifi1: unifi_siwessid: Join failed, status -5
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Input/output error.
```

Here the procedure I follow to activate connection on protected network, and what I try to do to swicth on free network:

```
#Wireless Function(protected_networks) 
wpa_passphrase "${SSIDNAME}" "${TYPE_PW}" > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf 
ifconfig wlan0 up 
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dwext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B 
udhcpc -iwlan0
```

then i turn off connection:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
killall udhcpc
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

and try to open connection on free Wi-Fi network:

```
#Wireless Function(free networks)
iwconfig wlan0 channel x (x=channel number)
iwconfig wlan0 essid "${SSIDNAME}"
udhcpc -iwlan0
```

Here I get the error i wrote above. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I also tried to delete `ifconfig wlan0 down` instruction from my procedure, but the result didn't change

Comment: Do you think it can be a driver problem? Also if I can connect to the same network when I didn't connect to any other protected networks before?